# Select All users who has not logged their time in last 5 days in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

i have 2 tables (joined on the base of user_id) ;

```
1 = Task ( id, user_id,task_title,created_datetime)
2 = users  (id,name)
```

I want to get all the users email who has not logged their time in last 5 days.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Sub query as below-

```
SELECT * FROM users  
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT A.id
    FROM users A
    INNER JOIN Task B ON A.id = B.user_id
    GROUP BY A.id
    HAVING  MAX(created_datetime) < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 DAY)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your tables definitions are like this :
1 = Task ( id, user_id, task_title, created_datetime)
2 = users  (id, name, email)
and you are using created_datetime to store logged in time, then following query should work:

```
SELECT email FROM users  
WHERE id not IN (
    SELECT distinct A.id
    FROM users A
    INNER JOIN Task B ON A.id = B.user_id
    where  A.created_datetime > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -5 DAY)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following :

```
SELECT a.*
FROM users a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT *
     FROM (SELECT *
           FROM task
           ORDER BY created_datetime DESC) AS a
     GROUP BY a.user_id ) AS b
ON a.id = b.user_id
WHERE b.created_datetime < CURRENT_DATE - interval 5 day;
```